# ExtJS 4 - Drag and drop image within a panel

Tags: extjs

I am adding an image onto a Panel like this:

```
var mypanel = this.getMyPanel2();
element = Ext.create('Ext.Img', {    
src: 'http://www.sencha.com/img/20110215-feat-html5.png',
renderTo: Ext.getBody()
});
mypanel.add(element);
```

(MyPanel2 being an Ext.panel.Panel)

The image gets added correctly.

Now I am trying to drag and drop the image within this panel. First I tried to set the panel draggable, but this only allows the panel to get dragged.

Do I have to set this panel as a drop area so the image can be drag and dropped?

Many thanks in advance!

M

Comment: You will have to set up a dropzone. Drag and drop is pretty complicated. I recommend looking at some of the samples on Sencha's site. http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/examples/#sample-9

Comment: I've taken the decision of adding a new panel to the original panel, and the former will have an image. This way I can drag&drop the panel within the original panel.